# What's the best way to figure out why my site is slow?

Tags: performance, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wordpress site painfully slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050329/wordpress-site-painfully-slow)

My site is very slow. There's a lot going on in terms of images and javascript, but I've gone through and temporarily removed big chunks of the site and tested the speed to see how it improved and it wasn't by much. I'm thinking that it must be something that's not obviously visible. What's the best way to figure out what is slowing it down? The site is http://www.art-start.org

Thanks!

Comment: @AlexD - I see your point I will remove my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Not a programming question but can give you a pretty good insight.

I strongly suggest you read up on and learn how to use [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) (makes things a whole lot easier)

The main thing that jumped out at me was your custom font (HVD_PPoster-webfont.woff) is 450kb.

Things I suggest to do are:

1. Following whatever [Google PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) says you should do
2. Install one of the wordpress caching plugins ([WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/))
3. Find a better solution for your custom font

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks cub3! It actually did turn out to be HVD_Poster and now the site is WAY faster.

Comment: No worries, if you could mark it as answered it would be appreciated